# How to access 2d array in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

How to use 2d array in assembly? i declarated `int array[100][2]` in C , and i want to access for example `array[4][0]` in assembly

Comment: A "2d" array is really an ***array of arrays***. Now try to draw it out on paper how such an array would look like in memory and it should all come naturally.

Comment: By the way, why have an array of a single element? Why not simply have `int array[100]` instead?

Comment: because i need to save 2 integers , one in 'array[0][0]' and other in 'array[0][1]

Comment: *need to [access] `array[0][0]` [&] `array[0][1]`* difficult (Asian style) given `int array[100][1]`.

Comment: Write an array mapping function.  If that's unfamiliar, google it. :)

Comment: You do know that when declaring an array the number inside the `[]` is the *size*, it's the number of elements and not the max index. For an array (of arrays) of *two* integers then that should be `int array[100][2]`.

Comment: sorry i was confused , you rigth , i need to pass 'array[0][0]' [&] 'array[0][1]' and the array declarated in C is  int array[100][2] i was looking in google and is something like this:  'mov ebx,5*100*4+5*4'
'mov eax,[Array + ebx]' ; Array[5][5] is now in eax.

Comment: You could also write the code in C and see the assembler output - I recommend Compiler Explorer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C,

```
array[i][j]
```

is the same as:

```
*(*(array + i) + j)
```

When you add pointers in C, it automatically takes into account the size of the type that is pointed to. That isn't the case in assembly, so you have to do that yourself.

The basic formula is just:

```
(offsetof(array) + (sizeof(int) * i)) + (sizeof(int) * j)
```

Since an `int` is almost certainly 4 bytes, the assembly equivalent of:

```
int temp = array[4][0];
```

would be:

```
mov  eax, DWORD PTR [array+16]
```

because (4*4)+(0*4) == 16.

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer, i actually use visual studio , C with assembly inline , i have other question ,its the reverse , how i assing an int to the array in assembly? for example i have in the register eax one number and i want to put in the position array[0][1]

Comment: Note that while this is correct, keep in mind that if `array` is an array of arrays, an implicit take-address is introduced when converting `array[i]` into a pointer to the first element of `array[i]`, so the actual pseudo code is something like `*(type*)&*(array + i) + j)`, i.e. `*(type*)(array + i)`.

Comment: Reverse the order of the operands, @Renzo: `mov DWORD PTR [array+16], eax`. As any book on assembly language will tell you, in Intel syntax, you have: `opcode destination, source`.